# ubuntu arm on android

Tags: android

i want to install ubuntu arm on a mobile phone as primary os. anybody know how to do this.
i want this as a ubuntu desktop.i have a samsung s4.i want to replace kernel and os with orginal linux kernel and ubuntu arm version.
Or any way to do this?

Comment: No way: https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Touch/Devices

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Replace android with ubuntu (arm )](http://askubuntu.com/questions/860055/replace-android-with-ubuntu-arm)

Comment: There is a way to use Ubuntu as a secondary OS. https://askubuntu.com/q/1332171/124466

Answer (score 0):

I think that there is a solution on Ubuntu website. If you have your desktop or laptop computer, then you can try this, but it is not stable and any few devices are supported...

Here is the supported devices: 
https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Touch/Devices

And here is the way to install ubuntu for phone:
https://developer.ubuntu.com/en/phone/devices/installing-ubuntu-for-devices/