# How to visualize Indic characters in Ubuntu minimum installation from base image?

Tags: fonts, ubuntu-minimal

I have [set up](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1332171/how-can-i-set-up-ubuntu-base-image-for-arm-on-my-android-phone-without-rooting) an Ubuntu base image, and installed XFCE desktop.

However, Indic characters in the filenames do not show up, some boxes are shown instead.

How to fix this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Install the packages for Noto Fonts. The package `fonts-noto-core` covers common unicode characters.

```
sudo apt install fonts-noto-core
```

If you need more unicode characters, run `apt search noto`, and install the package you would need. Alternatively, use synaptic to find the appropriate package.