# When Ubuntu has been depended to Python?

Tags: python, history-of-ubuntu

I'd like to know when Ubuntu has been depended to Python. I've found out that bionic already does. When Ubuntu has been depended to Python?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Many core GUI apps in Ubuntu are written in Python. Python is installed by default on Ubuntu Desktop since its very first release, 4.10.

However, Python is not required for a bare minimum CLI distro. [Ubuntu Base](https://askubuntu.com/q/1332171/124466) images don't have GUI preinstalled, and they don't have python preinstalled. But you can install python on them using `apt`.